# Как правильно передать конфигурацию в проект на Flask внутри Docker-контейнера?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, config, ci-cd

Здравстуйте всем!

Вопрос в следующем. Я недавно начал вливаться в Docker и CI/CD. У меня получилось настроить запуск проекта внутри контейнера, написал .gitlab-ci.yml скрипт, который будет создавать image при запушивании кода в репозиторий и сохранять его в гитлабовский Container Registry, зарегистрировал gitlab runner. В общем, все работает до момента, когда проекту требуются конфиги, потому что файл с конфигами нельзя хранить в репозитории с кодом.

Я мог бы попробовать использовать переменные среды, но тогда мне надо будет прокидывать их внутрь контейнера, а из него внутрь виртуальной среды Python. Не уверен, насколько правильно делать такое. Проблема с файлом заключается в том, что мне нужно каким-то образом обратиться к хостовой машине, на которой запущен контейнер, чтобы его получить. Опять же, не уверен в правильности этого.

Как правильно это сделать?

**Dockerfile**

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /application

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gunicorn3 && \
    apt-get install -y locales && \
    sed -i -e 's/# ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8/ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales

ENV LANG ru_RU.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL ru_RU.UTF-8

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt

COPY . ./

CMD ["gunicorn", "wsgi:application", "--config=./gunicorn-config.py"]
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - build

docker-build:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  before_script:
    - echo "$CI_BUILD_TOKEN" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - |
      if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH" ]]; then
        tag=""
        echo "Running on default branch '$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH': tag = 'latest'"
      else
        tag=":$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
        echo "Running on branch '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH': tag = $tag"
      fi
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}"
  after_script:
    - docker logout registry.gitlab.com
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: Вас устроит передача параметров контейнеру через командную строку при его запуске?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, рассмотрю любые варианты)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил свою проблему, использовав [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

1. Создал файлик с конфигами и разместил его по пути `/etc/my_service/config.yml` (это пример, можно использовать любой другой путь). Вот пример содержимого конфига:

> ```
> service:
>   string: string
>   number: 80
>   bool: false
> ```

2. Модуль `config.py` в проекте будет выглядеть следующим образом:

> ```
> import yaml
>
>
> def parse(path):
>     with open(path) as file:
>         return yaml.full_load(file)
>
> __CONFIG_PATH = "/etc/my_service/config.yml"
> __CONFIG = parse(__CONFIG_PATH)
>
> CONFIG_STRING = __CONFIG["service"]["string"]  # "string"
> CONFIG_NUMBER = __CONFIG["service"]["number"]  # 80
> CONFIG_BOOLEAN = __CONFIG["service"]["bool"]   # False
> ```

3. В `docker-compose.yml` к своему сервису добавил следующие строки:

> ```
> volumes:
>   - "/etc/my_service/config.yml:/etc/my_service/config.yml:ro"
> ```